# Connect to bluetooth device via socket to open communication

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Actually I have this scenario with a custom device I try to connect with Android Java application:
This custom device has a webserver inside

Connections implemented successful:

- WiFi;
- Hotspot;

I communicate with this webserver via `HTTP object requests` where I ask some parameters
My goal now is I want to add also Bluetooth connection possibility and communicate to the webserver when I need to connect directly to the custom device.

Since I am total novice on `Bluetooth` , to understand how connection for `Bluetooth` works, my actual implementation is:

```
private void printGattTable() {
    if (services.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("printGattTable", "No service and characteristic available, call discoverServices() first?");
    }

    services.forEach(service ->  {
        characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
        characteristics.listIterator();
        characteristics.forEach( characteristic -> {
            List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors();
            descriptor.forEach(singleDescriptor -> {
                Log.d("printGattTable", "singleDescriptor found: " + singleDescriptor.toString() );
            });
        });

    });
}

private void scanBondedBLEDevices()
{
    localIPs_BT.clear();
    localHostnames_BT.clear();
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!(mBluetoothAdapter == null) && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(bt_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            System.out.println("BLUETOOTH_CONNECT not granted?!?!?");
            return;
        }
        // retrieve bonded devices ( even if a new device is connected via BT is paired )
        //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothSet = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();  // because already paired on mobile
        if (bluetoothSet.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : bluetoothSet) {
                localIPs_BT.add(device.getAddress());
                localHostnames_BT.add(device.getName());
                ParcelUuid[] deviceUuids = device.getUuids();
                localUUIDs.add(deviceUuids);
                System.out.println("All paired devices checked?....");
            }
        }

        if (!localIPs_BT.isEmpty() && localIPs_BT.size() > 0) {
            uuidIndex = 0;
            try {
                localIPs_BT.forEach((currentIpAddress) -> {

                    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(currentIpAddress);

                        BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

                                Log.d("onConnectionStateChange_BT", "onConnectionStateChange status: " + status + " for MACAddress: " + currentIpAddress);
                                if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
                                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(bt_context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        // TODO: Consider calling
                                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                                        Log.d("BluetoothGattCallback", "Successfully connected to $deviceAddress");
                                        // TODO: Store a reference to BluetoothGatt
                                        gatt.discoverServices();
                                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                        Log.d("BluetoothGattCallback", "Successfully disconnected from $deviceAddress");
                                        gatt.close();
                                    }
                                } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.d("testBTconnection", "Disconnected from GATT server" + " for MACAddress: " + currentIpAddress);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                                super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

                                Log.e("onServicesDiscovered BT", "onServicesDiscovered status: " + status + " for MACAddress: " + currentIpAddress);
                                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                                /*
                                BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(YOUR_SERVICE_UUID);
                                if (service != null) {
                                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(YOUR_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                                    if (characteristic != null) {
                                    }
                                }
                                */
                                    services = gatt.getServices();

                                    //BluetoothSocket btSocket = new BluetoothSocket();

                                    printGattTable();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("testBTconnection", "Service discovery failed with status: " + status + " for MACAddress: " + currentIpAddress);
                                }
                            }
                            
                            @Override
                            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                                super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

                                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                                }
                            }

                        };

                        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(bt_context, false, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
                        //mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(bt_context, true, gattCallback);
                    }
                });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I added in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="true" />
```

With this implementation I got to understand how `Bluetooth` connection works for example connecting to my Garmin Forerunner where debugging the connection I can see `ArrayList` / `List` of my Garmin's `services` / `characteristics` ...
Always while debugging, I see also a list of `UUID` s where I suppose each of them is related to its functionality of my Garmin I am debugging in test...

If I want to communicate to custom device's websever through bluetooth , do I have to mount a common Bluetooth SoC or do I have to choose a certain type of SoC, maybe one to configure a custom UUID for HTTP connection with a `BluetoothGattService` ?
And if the solution is a custom Bluetooth SoC chip where set a custom `UUID` , how to send `HTTP object request` with a `BluetoothGattService` if it is the way to use?

Comment: If the target device is a Bluetooth LE (Bluetooth 4 and above) then you must use the [BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt) API in order to establish a connection to that device. Have a look at [Bluetooth LE Connection Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-gatt-server) so that you connect properly.

Comment: @Kozmotronik , I re-edited the post after adopting GATT as you said for BLE devices but I always get stuck at `newState` which gives me always `0` which means `STATE_DISCONNECTED` even if the device is correctly paired and connected on bluetooth as I can see in my mobile bluetooth active devices....

Comment: You try to connect to all bonded devices one by one. However are you sure that those devices are online or in range? Another point to note, if your intention is scanning for BLE devices, you do not scanning at all in your code. All you do is to get bonded devices and connect them. But you should have this in mind; not all devices necessarily create bond during their connection phase. If your peripheral devices are not configured to use encrypted communication, probably you do not find them in the `getBondedDevices` set.

Comment: What I can recommend you, is to have your peripheral device's MAC address hardcoded as `String` in your code. Then you should call `getRemoteDevice` by passing this hardcoded MAC string as its parameter to let the `BluetoothAdapter` create a new `BluetoothDevice` instance for you. Finally implement a `BluetoothGattCallback` for this device and then call the `device.connectGatt` method. But make sure that the peripheral device is online and in range before trying to establish a connection.

Comment: Develop your BLE code for a single hardcoded MAC peripheral until you can handle all required events successfully. When you get it working, start to develop your code step by step but with small steps so that it can handle multiple connections. I don't promise but I will try to write a bare minimal example working code that handles a BLE connection and communication. Good luck.

Comment: HI @Kozmotronik ! I tried to change the device with my Garmin smartwatch and this time at least I reached GATT_SUCCESS.... I re-edited again the post because I have still a doubt and question is there...

Comment: I think this question is pretty confusing what you are actually asking. You are talking about Bluetooth, wifi and http requests in the same question, although web and Bluetooth are two completely different topics. If you don't know how to even connect to a Bluetooth device in the first place, I suggest to first learn how Bluetooth or BLE works by reading on the subject.

Comment: Hello @Emil , I reposted completely the question to be more clear about my goal... is that exmplained better and more clear now?....

Comment: @Luigino hi! Can you specify the exact model of your Garmin smartwatch? Because the models I see, just don't have WiFi connectivity but only Bluetooth. What I understand from your question is that you want to implement http functionalities over the Bluetooth communication. But what do you know about the services of your smartwatch? You also ask for using a SoC for Bluetooth com. but why while you can connect directly to your smartwatch?

Comment: I think you better follow the [Garmin's guidelines](https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/core-topics/mobile-sdk-for-android/) for Android development.

Comment: Hi @Kozmotronik , yeah but I don't need really for Garmin services/characteristics but as like as I reposted completely the question my goal is having custom device, where there's a webserver inside I can query via http to obtain some data from sensors like battery for example, I would send http objects through Bluetooth connection, like HTTP over GATT, and have a response....

Comment: I see. However, as Emil has mentioned, why would you use http object while you can make services and characteristics for any data on your custom device. This is what Bluetooth GATT designed for. I can't give you any sight regarding the HTTP over GATT since I've never experimented it. But I can help for connection and data transferring with BLE.

Comment: @Kozmotronik , I was thinking for HTTP over GATT because webserver listens to commands like `http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/web.cgi?param0=XXX&param1=XXXX&param2=XXXXX` .... maybe that could be converted in services / characteristics? If yes , I guess on that custom device I should mount a custom `Bluetooth SoC` programmed with a predefined `UUID` so I can use to open a service, right?....